# Node.js on Windows, piping multiple scripts

Tags: windows, node.js, unix, stream, piping

I am using node.js on windows and I want to create separate .js scripts that I can treat individually like executables, and pipe the stdout from one executable as the stdin to another executable, in a Unix-like fashion.

There is technically a "|" operator in Windows but in my experience it does not work well at all. I am trying to implement a custom approach in node.js. The syntax can be different, something like,

```
node combine "somescript 1" "someotherscript"
```

Where combine.js is the script which handles piping the output of "node somescript 1" to the input of "node someotherscript". Here is my attempt so far but I could use some assistance, I am fairly new to node.js,

```
 var child = require('child_process');

 var firstArgs = process.argv[2].split(' '); 

 var firstChild = child.spawn('node', firstArgs);

 var secondChild = child.spawn('node');

 firstChild.stdout.pipe(secondChild.stdin, { end: false });

 secondChild.stdout.pipe(process.stdout, { end: false }); 

 secondChild.on('exit', function (code) {
   process.exit(code);
 });
```

Thanks!

Comment: You never actually say, but I assume this example doesn't work? What specifically is your question? What is `process`? If it is an arbitrary command, why are you spawning node?

Comment: I think process refers to the currently running process. The example does not work. The std output of firstchild should be the std input to secondchild, and the std output of secondchild should be in std output of the current process.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear, process is a script file, as in process.js. So "node process" will run process.js. But process is also a way to refer to the current process, e.g as in process.argv, I think? I can see its confusing, I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use Node.js [Transform](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) streams for your scripts, and use `combine.js` to `require` and `pipe` those streams, based on command line arguments.

Example:

```js
// stream1.js
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;

var stream1 = new Transform();
stream1._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  this.push(chunk.toString() + 's1\r\n');
  done();
};

module.exports = stream1;

// stream2.js
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;

var stream2 = new Transform();
stream2._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  this.push(chunk.toString() + 's2\r\n');
  done();
};

module.exports = stream2;

// combine.js

var stream1 = require('./' + process.argv[2]);
var stream2 = require('./' + process.argv[3]);

process.stdin.pipe(stream1).pipe(stream2).pipe(process.stdout);
```

That way running:

```
> echo "hi" | node stream1 stream2
```

Should output:

```
hi
s1
s2
```